# summing up expressions in a 2d list- python 2

Tags: python, list, sum, sympy

As of now, I have a 2d lists whose nested elements id like to add up row-wise, instead of having them be separate.

The list looks like this,

```
Mb=[[ab*(1-r)**4, cb*(r)**5], [bc(1-p)**5, (1-pdc)**2*r]]
```

and Id like the output to look something like this,

```
B=[[ab*(1-r)**4+cb*(r)**5], [bc(1-p)**5+(1-pdc)**2*r]]
```

Ive already defined the ab, r, p etc as variables using (ab, r, p= sp.symbols('ab, r, p')) but Im having trouble fining a code that sums up the elements inside a nested list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sympy, the class to represent a sum is `Add` and `sum` will automatically apply the `__add__` operator and, since you are adding sympy `Expr` objects, the result will be a sympy `Add`. So using `sum(i)` or `Add(*i)` in the following will work:

```
B = [[Add(*i)] for i in Mb]
```

Note that in the case of `Add` you must unpack the elements with `*` whereas in the case of using `sum` you do not.